# error de syntaxis CREATE TRIGGER La función de creación debe ser la única declaración en el lote

Tags: sql-server, trigger, sintaxis

```
 CREATE TRIGGER ti_aprobado ON NOTA FOR INSERT AS
 BEGIN
    DECLARE
    @cedula char(10);
    @cod_mat char(10);
    @anio smallint;
    @apro bit;
    @valor_nota decimal(3,0);
    @cod_nota char(10);

    SELECT @cedula=cedula;
        @cod_mat=cod_materia;
        @anio=year(fecha_nota);
        @valor_nota=valor_nota;
        @cod_nota=cod_nota;
    FROM INSERTED;

   IF @cod_nota='NF';
   BEGIN
       IF @valor_nota <30;
          SELECT @apro=0;
       ELSE
          SELECT @apro=1;
   END

   INSERT INTO APROBADO VALUES(@cedula,@cod_mat,@anio,@apro);

END
```

Comment: Tienes un montón de puntos y comas que sobran. En Declare, al ponerlo una vez, cada una de las variables debe de ir separada con coma. Excepto `@cod_nota char(10);` que terminará con punto y coma. Los ifs tampoco llevan punto y coma. Lo lleva la select que hay como solución del if, pero no su comparación. Y con eso el trigger será lo que has programado. ¿Pero que pasa si haces un insert a notas con varias filas? No funcionará bien.

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchas cosas incorrectas con este código. Empezando por todos los errores de sintaxis al poner punto y coma donde no van y generando errores.

El error se debe probablemente a que tienes una instrucción antes del CREATE TRIGGER que se está ejecutando en la misma cadena de comandos. Para evitar eso, debes usar un GO.

Pero lo más importante, es que ese trigger solo puede funcionar con inserciones de una sola fila. Si se insertan más de 1 fila al mismo tiempo, solo tomará una. Para corregirlo, solo hay que simplificar el código.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE name = 'ti_aprobado')
    DROP TRIGGER ti_aprobado
GO
CREATE TRIGGER ti_aprobado ON NOTA 
FOR INSERT AS

INSERT INTO APROBADO 
SELECT  cedula,
        cod_mat,
        anio,
        CASE WHEN cod_nota='NF' AND valor_nota >= 30 
             THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 END
FROM inserted;
GO
```

Por último, insertat en una tabla distinta para identificar a los aprobados es una duplicación tremedna de datos. Lo que debes de hacer es agregar una columna a la tabla de `Nota` para identificar las notas aprobadas. Si esto es un trabajo escolar que exige el uso de triggers, te recomiendo que busques algo que sea más funcional.